# How to set pseudo elements properties dynamically?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, pseudo-element

I am trying to overlay a watermark on a HTML5 video, and depending on the user selection, set the position of the watermark on the video.

CSS

```
/*Video.module.css*/

.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
}

.wrapper::before {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 2%;
    left: 2%;
    height: 18%;
    width: 18%;
    content: '';
    background: 'red';
}
```

JSX

```
import styles from 'styles/Video.module.css';

const Video = ({ src }) => {
    return (
        <div class={styles.wrapper}>
            <video src={src}>
                <track type='captions' />
            </video>
        </div>
    );
};
```

With the current styles, the watermark is positioned at the top-left of the video. I want to  allow the user to select the position.

Currently, my approach is to create a css class selector for each position like below and use useState hook to set the class based on user selection.

CSS

```
.wrapper-top-right {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
}

.wrapper-top-right::before {
    top: 2%
    right: 2%
    ....
}

.wrapper-bottom-right {
    ....
}

.wrapper-bottom-right::before {
    bottom: 2%;
    right: 2%;
    ....
}
```

JSX

```
import styles from 'styles/Video.module.css';
import React, {useState} from 'react';

const Video = ({ src }) => {
    //Values: 'top-left', 'bottom-left', 'top-right', 'bottom-right'
    const [position, setPosition] = useState('top-left'); 

    return (
        <div class={`styles[${position}]`}>
            <video src={src}>
                <track type='captions' />
            </video>
            /** Button with code to set position.... **/
        </div>
    );
};
```

But this is definitely not ideal due to the repeated code within the CSS file. Would like to know if there is way to set the properties (in this case, `top, bottom, left, right`) dynamically so that I only need a single class selector.

Comment: You can't set style for pseudo elements dynamically, but maybe CSS variables can be a solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS custom properties set for host element.

I don't speak React, so quick vanilla POC:

```css
.wrapper::before {
  position: absolute;
  top: var(--before-top, 0%);
  left: var(--before-left, 0%);
  background: red;
  color: white;
  content: var(--before-content, '?');
}
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  outline: #0FF6 solid;
  outline-offset: -2px;
}
label { display: block; }
```

```html
<label>Top: <input type="range" value="0" min="0" max="100" 
 oninput="w.style.setProperty('--before-top', this.value + '%')"></label>
<label>Left: <input type="range" value="0" min="0" max="100" 
 oninput="w.style.setProperty('--before-left', this.value + '%')"></label>
<label>Content: <input type="text" value="?" 
 oninput="w.style.setProperty('--before-content', `'${this.value}'`)"></label>
<div class="wrapper" id="w"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set a `--custom-property` on the parent element. I'll change the values with :hover here, but you should be able to see how it could be done within a `style` attribute as well:

```css
div {

  /* Important bits */
  --watermarkBottom: 0;
  --watermarkTop: initial;

  /* Boilerplate */
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color:red;
  position: relative;
}

div:hover {
  /* Important bits */
  --watermarkBottom: initial;
  --watermarkTop: 0;
}

div::after {
  /* Important bits */
  bottom: var(--watermarkBottom);
  top: var(--watermarkTop);

  /* Boilerplate */
  content: 'watermark';
  background-color:blue;
  color:white;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```